# How can I host a server from two domains?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

I have two domains in Cloudflare. I want to use those two domains for my application.

For example, [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com), [www.xzy.com](http://www.xzy.com)

They should host the same server. I created load balancers and target groups for ECS Clusters. They are working but there is one problem. The problem is the first target group's Registered target is updated automatically, but the second one can't do it. Because I can just define one target group for ECS Fargate. So after every deployment, I have to change the registered target manually. How can I do it automatically?

Comment: "The problem is the first target group's Registered target is updated automatically, but the second one can't do it. Because I can just define one target group for ECS Fargate." You need to describe your problem in more detail. Hosting two websites/domains on a single container on Fargate, or are you running multiple containers in the same Fargate task, each serving a different domain? Your ECS Service should be able to register with multiple target groups: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/register-multiple-targetgroups.html there is no restriction for Fargate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have an application on Fargate. We have two domains on Cloudflare. We were using the first domain for our application. Then we wanted to use both domains for our application and I created a load balancer, and target groups. After every deployment, I have to change the registered target groups' IPs manually.

Comment: All you have done in this comment is repeat what you already stated in your question. You didn't answer any of my questions. Are you saying both domains are hosted by the same container in your ECS task definition? What specifically are you running into with the target groups since AWS ECS Fargate absolutely allow multiple target groups you must be doing something wrong. If both domains are served by the same ECS task, and on the same port, then you don't even need multiple target groups.

Comment: "Are you saying both domains are hosted by the same container in your ECS task definition? " actually this is what I want to achieve

Comment: Then why do you have two target groups if the target is always the same container?

Comment: because I have two different domains and I thought I had to create a new load balancer. When I was creating a load balancer, I had to select target groups but I could not select them because they are in use. So I created a new target group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251009/discussion-between-kemal-mutlu-and-mark-b).

Answer (score -1):

AWS ALB supports host-based routing by using Host header.

You can follow this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/vi/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/) to setup

Comment: This is a link-only-answer that will become useless if the link breaks.

Comment: Why does it break? I still can see it

Comment: And it is AWS blog link, so I don't think it will break

Comment: It sounds like they are already using host based routing, but are having trouble with the routing targets.